# Google Scripts, for loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a dynamic googledoc that uses %Address0%, %Address1%, %Address2%, etc. to populate from a spreadsheet that contains the information. my current code works for all of the first %description0% 's but the susequent %desription1%,%description2% are not populating. Im guessing my for-loop is not iterating past the first iteration or for some reason the body cannot be modified twice, but I can't find anything in the supporting documentation that would give me that idea.

Also, I ruled out the possibility of it being something wrong with the var data, I can get all the properties one at a time, for example: I can get the %Address0%, %Type0%, %Price0% to populate correctly OR I can get %Address1%, %Type1%, %Price1% but I can't get them to do it all at once.

```
// create a menu
function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Create CMA", functionName: "CreateCMA"}];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.addMenu("CMA Generator", menuEntries);
}

function CreateCMA() {
  var templateid = "1uLC41M1B0KjtC_AlxFAT2h2_9HPLsLSk4HPhXgq2ebY"; // template file id
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,6,11).getValues(); // starting with row 2 and column 1 as our upper-left most column
  var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy().getId();
  // Create our number formatter.
  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  });
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);

  for (var r = 0; r < 6; r++){
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var row = data[r];
    body.replaceText("%Address" + r + "%", row[0]);
    body.replaceText("%Type" + r + "%", row[1]);
    body.replaceText("%Price" + r + "%", formatter.format(row[2]));
    var date = row[3];
    var dateform = Utilities.formatDate(date, "+5", "dd MMM yyyy");
    body.replaceText("%Date" + r + "%", dateform);
    body.replaceText("%Built" + r + "%", row[4]);
    body.replaceText("%Square_ft" + r + "%", row[5]);
    body.replaceText("%Bedroom" + r + "%", row[6]);
    body.replaceText("%Bath" + r + "%", row[7]);
    body.replaceText("%Assessed_Val" + r + "%", formatter.format(row[8]));
    body.replaceText("%Initial_Ask" + r + "%", formatter.format(row[9]));
    var post = row[10];
    var postform = Utilities.formatDate(post, "+5", "dd MMM yyyy");
    body.replaceText("%Day_Posted" + r + "%", postform);
  }
    doc.saveAndClose();

}
```

Comment: try moving `var body = doc.getBody();` outside the loop

Comment: Thank you for the shot but I had already tried that.

Comment: Add `console.log(r)` inside the loop and see if it executes 6 times

Comment: It gives me this error.   [20-04-18 16:17:50:392 PDT] Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.
    at CreateCMA(Code:61:30).  I probably should have mentioned that I knew it was throwing an error but it still executes at least some code after that because all of the %descriptions% will populate. but to answer your original question, the logger only prints out this error.

Comment: `row[10]` is not formatted as a date in Google sheets